# TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) on Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, python-2.x

```
$ python code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from implementation import *
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/snowb/OneDrive/Desktop/Artificial 
Intelligence/Program 2/code/implementation.py", line 96, in <module>
    diagram4 = GridWithWeights(10, 10)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/snowb/OneDrive/Desktop/Artificial 
Intelligence/Program 2/code/implementation.py", line 90, in __init__
    super().__init__(width, height)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

On my system I am using a 64-bit Intel Processor. I have just re-installed Python 3.x-64 bit using the automatic settings and am still receiving the error above. I have browsed around and have seen that this is a common issue with Python 2.x installed and running Python3.x code, however I am definitely using Python 3.x.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.104]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\snowb>python --version
Python 3.7.1

C:\Users\snowb>where python
C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\python

C:\Users\snowb>
```

Here is a screenshot of my [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGG9t.png).

I am unsure of how to proceed in order to fix this. Can anyone offer any advice as to what is happening?

EDIT: The problem has been fixed. I have run the same commands on cmd (instead of cygwin), and the code executed as expected. Cygwin is most likely using an internal Python implementation which must be changed by managing its packages.

Comment: TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not instance, with the change of coldspeed

Comment: Sorry, replace `self` with your class name. Also, I would be a lot more comfortable if you could post the code instead of only the traceback, or perhaps ideally a [mcve].

Comment: That's not a python 3 error. You *are* using python 2.

Comment: http://codepad.org/sg4DiYVl

Comment: thanks for the response Aran, but there is no python 2 distribution anywhere on my system.

Comment: Open your cmd, run `python --version` and `where python` and paste the outputs into your question.

Comment: The code in your codepad throws a completely different error, by the way.

Comment: Well, apparently there's python 2 in cygwin.

Comment: yes, that is another python 2 error when using python 3 constructs. and im not sure how launching my program from a cygwin terminal would matter, since the only distribution of python on my system is 3.x and cygwin pulls that implementation from PATH which is provided above. either that, or i am misunderstanding how things work

Comment: I agree with @Aran-Fey, somehow your code is getting run with Py2. Stick an `import sys; print(sys.executable);print(sys.version)` at (almost) the top of your file (after the future import) to have it print which interpreter is being used. Other than that, I can't really offer any help, sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Windows-specifics.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I ran the code using command prompt and everything worked, however, I am still confused for the reasons stated in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with cygwin, so I have no idea how it ends up executing your code with python 2.